# Why can't I peek a sorted seq in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

while practicing with Clojure I noticed this. Peeking a vector works as expected:

```clj
(let [v (vector 1 2 3)]
  (peek v))
;; => 3
```

Peeking a list too:

```clj
(let [l (list 1 2 3)]
  (peek l))
;; => 1
```

However, if I first *sort* the sequence, it panics!

```clj
(let [l (sort (list 1 2 3))]
  (peek l))

;; => Unhandled java.lang.ClassCastException
   class clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast to class
   clojure.lang.IPersistentStack (clojure.lang.ArraySeq and
   clojure.lang.IPersistentStack are in unnamed module of loader
   'app')
```

**Why is that?** Thanks!

Comment: Imagine that `peek` *did* work. Which element (1 or 3) would you expect it to return, and why?

Comment: The docstring says: `For a list or queue, same as first, for a vector, same as, but much more efficient than, last. If the collection is empty, returns nil.` so I think there's no ambiguity, or is it? I mean, if I sort a list, I expect a list, if I sort a vector, I expect a vector (?)

Comment: Read the [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj) of `sort` and you will see that it is implemented by first converting to an array and then sorting using Java: `(. java.util.Arrays (sort a comp))` and then wraps the result with `(seq a)` which results in an `ArraySeq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying and slightly editing (striking the mention of `conj` because it's incorrect) [a good comment](https://clojurians.slack.com/archives/C03S1KBA2/p1585962576079300?thread_ts=1585942850.064100&cid=C03S1KBA2) by @potetm on Clojurians Slack:

> `cons`, `seq`, `map`, and `filter` are *sequence abstractions*. They’re designed to be lazy. They can be backed by any number of concrete data types or, potentially, none at all (e.g. infinite sequences).
>
> `list`, `vector`, and `PersistentQueue` are all *concrete data types*. They are designed to hold all contents in memory and to be very efficient at various operations, depending on the type. For example, `list` has a very efficient prepend operation, but poor indexed access. `vector` has a very efficient append operation and very efficient indexed access.
>
> In clojure, `peek`, `pop`<strike>, and conj</strike> are *queue functions*. They’re only available on *concrete data types* which implement the `IPersistentStack` interface. (That includes lists, vectors, and PersistentQueue.) This restriction is to quasi-guarantee that `peek` and `pop` will be extremely efficient (usually requiring no more than a single allocation). This also guarantees that each function *keeps the same data type* as the original collection (unlike sequence functions).

Comment: Interesting, thanks, but I am still missing a point: does this means that the value returned from `sort` is not concrete? How could I know?

Comment: Lazy answer: only use `peek` on vectors, when performance is very important. `first` and `last` work well enough and are generic.

Comment: @AlessandroBertulli From the docstring of `sort` - it states that it returns a _sequence_. The concept is certainly not something that immediately jumps at you when learning the language, but it's still well documented: https://clojure.org/reference/sequences

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

The `peek` function is only meant for use on a ***stack***.  In Clojure, either a `vector` or a `list` can serve as a stack.  For any other sequence type, just use `first` to get the initial element.

---

### More Details

If you read the Clojure source code, it uses the built-in Java sorting algorithm:

```
(defn sort
  "Returns a sorted sequence of the items in coll. If no comparator is
  supplied, uses compare.  comparator must implement
  java.util.Comparator.  Guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will
  not be reordered.  If coll is a Java array, it will be modified.  To
  avoid this, sort a copy of the array."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([coll]
   (sort compare coll))
  ([^java.util.Comparator comp coll]
   (if (seq coll)
     (let [a (to-array coll)]
       (. java.util.Arrays (sort a comp))
       (with-meta (seq a) (meta coll)))
     ())))
```

The function `to-array` "Maps to java.util.Collection.toArray()".  You can see a hint of this in the error missage `class clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast...`.  The `peek` function only operates on Clojure types, while `sort` returns a different type.

You can examine the superclasses & interfaces a Clojure type has as follows:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(verify
  (is= clojure.lang.ArraySeq (type (sort [1 2 3])))

  (is= (parents clojure.lang.ArraySeq)
    #{clojure.lang.ASeq
      clojure.lang.IReduce
      clojure.lang.IndexedSeq})

  (is= (ancestors clojure.lang.ArraySeq)
    #{clojure.lang.ASeq
      clojure.lang.Counted
      clojure.lang.IHashEq
      clojure.lang.IMeta
      clojure.lang.IObj
      clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection
      clojure.lang.IReduce
      clojure.lang.IReduceInit
      clojure.lang.ISeq
      clojure.lang.IndexedSeq
      clojure.lang.Obj
      clojure.lang.Seqable
      clojure.lang.Sequential
      java.io.Serializable
      java.lang.Iterable
      java.lang.Object
      java.util.Collection
      java.util.List})
  )
```

using [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

---

### P.S.

You can always coerce any sequence into a plain vector like:

```
(let [sv  (vec (sort (list 1 2 3)))]
  (peek sv))  ; <= should be either `first` or `last`
```

However, you should be explicit about what you want and use either `first` or `last`.

Comment: It does return a Clojure collection in the end though. It's just that that collection does not implement the `IPersistentStack` protocol. And I believe the OP's question boils down to why it doesn't implement it.

Comment: The short answer is also incomplete because it doesn't mention `clojure.lang.PersistentQueue`, which the docstring of `peek` mentions.